# Not able to click Button on a confirm box with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a bot. I got this html page where I click on a button (type="submit"). When it does, it pops up a small window, like a confirm box. I cannot view source of this confirm box as it is not shown on the html code. But from the javascript console I get this code from the message box:

```
<div class="confirmation-box" id="pop" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmation-msg">
<div><div style="text-align: left"></div>
<div class="confirmation-buttons">
<button class="btn evt-confirm-btn btn-confirm-yes" aria-label'confirmar'="">Confirmar</button>
<button class="btn evt-cancel-btn btn-confirm-no" aria-label'cancelar'="">Cancelar</button>
</div></div></div>
```

I've tried several javascript codes but I'm never able to click the 'Confirmar' button. It seems like the javascript code runs before the confirmation box pops up and doesn't recognize the ID and Class of the button.

My code:

```
// Clicks the button on the html page, working OK
....{document.forms[0].sell.value = y-x; 
document.querySelector('input[value="Calcular melhor oferta "]').click();
```

Now a confirmation box appears and I tried to use the next codes to click on the button that appears in the confirmation box, without sucess:

```
document.getElementById("pop").getElementsByClassName("confirmation-buttons").getElementsByClassName("evt-confirm-btn btn-confirm-yes")[0].click();}

document.getElementsByClassName("evt-confirm-btn")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("hello");});

document.getElementsByClassName("evt-confirm-btn")[0].click();}
```

It seems like if this code runs before the confirmation box appears.

Comment: not sure how is your javascript is implemented. If that dialog is being built dynamicallym then you should also bind the event after the dialog is created or your can alternatively use binding on parent `$('body').on('click', '.btn-confirm-yes', function(){alert();})` for example

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a click in code? It's not clear from your question. What have you tried so far that has been unsuccessful?

Comment: Edited main post.

Comment: there are some browser extensions that let you record your browser actions and convert them to different formats http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it using:

```
var timeOff=1000;
setInterval(time, timeOff);
function time()
{ document.getElementById("pop").getElementsByClassName("evt-confirm-btn btn-confirm-yes")[0].click();}}
```

This makes 1 second delay on the code, enough to run the small window before runing the rest of the code.